# I can't get data from user to calculate

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create a program that is a Bakery online shop but I'm stuck on a show bill page, I want to show the menu list, Amount, Price, Total of that cake or drink in one line and the last line is all total

this my code :

```
from tkinter import*
def mainwindow():
    main = Tk()
    x = main.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 - (w / 2)
    y = main.winfo_screenheight() / 2 - (h / 2)
    main.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (w, h, x, y))
    main.title("Cake_Shop by Winit Auppkarasakun")
    main.option_add("*font", "times 17 bold")


    menubar = Menu(main)
    filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=False)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Menu", command=menu)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Checkout", command=checkout)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=main.quit)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
    main.configure(bg="pink", menu=menubar)
    return main

def menu():

    frame1 = Frame(main, bg="yellow")
    frame1.place(x=0, y=0, width=w, height=h)
    frame1.columnconfigure((0,1), weight=1)
    frame1.rowconfigure((0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), weight=1)

    Label(frame1, text="Strawberry Cake : ", bg="yellow", fg="blue", font="times 18 bold").grid(row=0, column=0)
    Label(frame1, image = img_menu_1, bg="yellow").grid(row=1, column=0)
    Label(frame1, text="Price 85", bg="yellow", fg="black").grid(row=2, column=0)
    Spinbox(frame1, from_=0, to=10, textvariable=cake_spy1).grid(row=3, column=0)

    Label(frame1, text="Cheese Cake : ", bg="yellow", fg="blue", font="times 18 bold").grid(row=4, column=0)
    Label(frame1, image = img_menu_2, bg="yellow").grid(row=5, column=0)
    Label(frame1, text="Price 95", bg="yellow", fg="black").grid(row=6, column=0)
    Spinbox(frame1, from_=0, to=10, textvariable=cake_spy2).grid(row=7, column=0)

    Label(frame1, text="Strawberry Mixed : ", bg="yellow", fg="blue", font="times 18 bold").grid(row=0, column=1)
    Label(frame1, image = img_drink_1, bg="yellow").grid(row=1, column=1)
    Label(frame1, text="Price 120", bg="yellow", fg="black").grid(row=2, column=1)
    Spinbox(frame1, from_=0, to=10, textvariable=drink_spy1).grid(row=3, column=1)

    Label(frame1, text="Orange Mixed : ", bg="yellow", fg="blue", font="times 18 bold").grid(row=4, column=1)
    Label(frame1, image = img_drink_2, bg="yellow").grid(row=5, column=1)
    Label(frame1, text="Price 140", bg="yellow", fg="black").grid(row=6, column=1)
    Spinbox(frame1, from_=0, to=10, textvariable=drink_spy2).grid(row=7, column=1)

def checkout():
    frame2 = Frame(main, bg="lightgreen")
    frame2.place(x=0, y=0, width=w, height=h)
    frame2.rowconfigure((0,1,2,3,4,5), weight=1)
    frame2.columnconfigure((0,1,2,3), weight=1)
    Label(frame2, text="Menu list", bg="lightgreen", fg="black").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N, pady=10)
    Label(frame2, text="Amount", bg="lightgreen", fg="black").grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N, pady=10)
    Label(frame2, text="Price", bg="lightgreen", fg="black").grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=N, pady=10)
    Label(frame2, text="Total(Baths)", bg="lightgreen", fg="black").grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=N, pady=10)

    for i,des in enumerate(name_menu_list):
        Label(frame2, text=des["Menu list"]).grid(row=i+1, column=0, sticky="news")
        Label(frame2, text=des["Amount"]).grid(row=i+1, column=1, sticky="news")
        Label(frame2, text=des["Price"]).grid(row=i+1, column=2, sticky="news")
        Label(frame2, text=des["Total(Baths)"]).grid(row=i+1, column=3, sticky="news")
    
def calculate():
    global total
    global menu_total
    menu_total = 0
    total = 0

    if cake_spy1.get() > 0:
        menu_total = cake_spy1.get() * 85
        total = total + menu_total
        show_menu = {"Menu list":"Strawberry Cake", "Amount":cake_spy1, "Price":85, "Total(Baths)":menu_total}
    
    elif cake_spy2.get() > 0:
        menu_total = cake_spy2.get() * 95
        total = total + menu_total
        show_menu = {"Menu list":"Cheese Cake", "Amount":cake_spy2, "Price":95, "Total(Baths)":menu_total}

    elif drink_spy1.get() > 0:
        menu_total = drink_spy1.get() * 120
        total = total + menu_total
        show_menu = {"Menu list":"Strawberry Mixed", "Amount":drink_spy1, "Price":120, "Total(Baths)":menu_total}

    elif drink_spy2.get() > 0:
        menu_total = drink_spy2.get() * 140
        total = total + menu_total
        show_menu = {"Menu list":"Orange Mixed", "Amount":drink_spy2, "Price":140, "Total(Baths)":menu_total}


    name_menu_list.append(show_menu)

menu_total = 0  
total = 0
w = 800
h = 700
main = mainwindow()
cake_spy1 = StringVar()
cake_spy2 = StringVar()
drink_spy1 = StringVar()
drink_spy2 = StringVar()
frame0 = Frame(main, bg="pink") #for homepage
frame0.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")
img_home = PhotoImage(file="images/myshop.png")
Label(frame0, image=img_home, bg="pink").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news", padx=130, pady=40)
Label(frame0, text="...Welcome to my resturent...", bg="pink", fg="black", font="times 25 bold").grid(row=1, column=0)

img_menu_1 = PhotoImage(file="images/cake1.png")
img_menu_2 = PhotoImage(file="images/cake2.png")
img_drink_1 = PhotoImage(file="images/drink1.png")
img_drink_2 = PhotoImage(file="images/drink2.png")

name_menu_list = []
menu_name = StringVar()

main.mainloop()
```

this all my code the problem function is checkout and calculate

Thank you for helping me

Comment: Please make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of the entire code and let us know the exact error faced by you.

Comment: change `filemenu.add_command(label="Checkout", command=checkout)` -> `filemenu.add_command(label="Checkout", command= lambda :calculate() or checkout())`  now change `cake_spy1 = StringVar() cake_spy2 = StringVar() drink_spy1 = StringVar() drink_spy2 = StringVar()` to an `IntVar()` eg:-  ``cake_spy1=IntVar()` also under `show_menu = {"Menu list":"Strawberry Cake", "Amount":cake_spy1, "Price":85, "Total(Baths)":menu_total}` should be ` `show_menu = {"Menu list":"Strawberry Cake", "Amount":cake_spy1.get(), "Price":85, "Total(Baths)":menu_total}` now if you are wondering why there is only one

Comment: item under checkout even when you have added two or more its because of your `elif` statements change all `elif` to just `if` and add `name_menu_list.append(show_menu)` under all the if statements.